# Interface 'Symfony\Contracts\Translation\LocaleAwareInterface' not found - When update laravel composer

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.7

I Update my Laravel Project Composer, I got Following

> Error. "**Interface
>   'Symfony\Contracts\Translation\LocaleAwareInterface' not found**"

how to resolve it.

My Laravel Project Version is: 5.7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

do a

```
 sudo chown -R $USER ~/.composer/
```

then

```
composer update
```

it should update the `symfony/contracts` package to the updated version.