# After update composer error show: Interface 'Symfony\Contracts\Translation\LocaleAwareInterface' not found

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.6

I update laravel project composer. Project build with laravel 5.6 version. After composer update I got following error. Please help how can resolve this issue?

### Interface 'Symfony\Contracts\Translation\LocaleAwareInterface' not found

error image: http://prnt.sc/mkkyfx

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Interface 'Symfony\Contracts\Translation\LocaleAwareInterface' not found - When update laravel composer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53668503/interface-symfony-contracts-translation-localeawareinterface-not-found-when)

Comment: I tried but I not clear this command line. sudo chown -R $USER ~/.composer/
Can you please little bit explain. I am using git bash. Thanks